# Continuos delivery pipeline for Android Applications

Tags: android, ant, continuous-integration, robotium

I am doing a little research on how to setup Continuos delivery pipeline for Android apps. I am aware of [existing approaches](http://www.multunus.com/2011/09/continuous-delivery-for-android-apps-part-1) of using Jenkins and Ant scripts for making a build. What I'd really like to do is when I do a git push on say a development branch, I'd like Jenkins to do a build on bunch of emulators (With different resolutions) run my Robotium scripts and email me results.

I am looking for end-to-end setup preferably the server would run on Ubuntu.

Comment: you can use **emma** in jenkins to do that.

Comment: @Atrix1987 if you can paste clickable link I'd appreciate it

Comment: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Android+Emulator+Plugin and for configuration https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+an+Android+app+and+test+project

Comment: @Atrix1987 thank you, these links are helpful. Do I need anything else for executing Robotium tasks or would plugin suffice?

Answer (score 1):

Siddharth,
You may want to consider CloudMunch for this need. All you need to do is launch the emulators as part your pipeline to test various stacks and finally get an update over mail. Robotium scripts can be called over shell and reports will come to you as mail at the end of the test.